# SSRS Dynamic Running Total

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to include a cumulative total column in a matrix on a report.
This is the expression I am using at the moment:

```
=RunningValue(Ceiling((SUM(Fields!MINUTES.Value)/60)*4)/4,Sum,"RowGroup")
```

The problem is the total seems to reset on each day.

I have 3 groups on the report: Parent is Day of month, type, then sub type.
I want it so that the sub types will accumulate across the days:

So 1st june/holiday/annual = 2 - cumulative = 2
.. 2nd june/holiday/annual = 1 - cumulative = 3

`rowgroup` in the expression above is the 3rd level sub type group in the matrix.

Whatever I try I cannot get it to total up over the days, like i said above it seems to not carry over to the next day.

Below is a sample dataset:

```
+------+------------+---------+----------+---------+
| User |    Date    |  Type   | Subtype  | Minutes |
+------+------------+---------+----------+---------+
|  158 | 13/02/2015 | Holiday | Annual   |      90 |
|  158 | 13/02/2015 | Meeting | Training |     300 |
|  158 | 13/02/2015 | Lunch   | Lunch    |      60 |
|  158 | 03/06/2015 | Holiday | Annual   |     120 |
|  158 | 03/06/2015 | Meeting | Meeting  |     285 |
|  158 | 04/06/2015 | Holiday | Sick     |     120 |
|  158 | 04/06/2015 | Holiday | Annual   |     200 |
+------+------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

My matrix column group is the user.
The row groups are date, then type, then subtype.

I then have a total column outside the column grouping.

I'm now trying to add in to the report a cumulative total based on the `type` and `sub-type` columns, that sums up the `minutes`.

As an example (looking at the `holiday`, `annual` entries):

```
03/06/2015 - 120 minutes
13/02/2015 - 90 minutes = 210 minutes 
04/06/2015 - 200 minutes = 410 minutes.
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [MSDN page for RunningValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd255229.aspx), adding a `scope` to your expression will have this effect.

> The value for RunningValue resets to 0 for each new instance of the scope. **If a group is specified, the running value is reset when the group expression changes.** If a data region is specified, the running value is reset for each new instance of the data region. If a dataset is specified, the running value is not reset throughout the entire dataset.

To fix the issue, simply remove the scope:

```
=RunningValue(Ceiling((SUM(Fields!MINUTES.Value)/60)*4)/4,Sum)
```

This will have the total run across all days (As days are your top-most level). If this is incorrect could you perhaps give us an example of what the report is currently doing, and what you want it to do?

Comment: hi, sorry will try to give more detailed example. my sql returns individual entries per day/type/sub type. so i have a column doing a sum on each grouping per day. so 1st june holiday annual sum = 2. 1st june holiday sick sum = 3. so that would mean the cumuluative column would have 2 and 3. and then the next line on matrix would be for 2nd june holiday annual sum = 4. so i want the cumulative column to be 6. i.e. 2 from the 1 st of june and the 4 from here. and so on and so on down the matrix. so basically a cumulative total running down the matrix for each type/subtype

Comment: Just change the scope of the RunningValue to whatever you want to accumulate across. I can't give a detailed example with the level of detail in your question. Post a sample data-set and I'll update my answer.

Comment: hi, i have updated the question to include sample data and more of an explanation of what i want it to do